# building deb packages: how to calc size information

Tags: debian-packaging

I'm using

```
fakeroot dpkg-deb --build my-package
```

to build a .deb package. I'm using a hand-crafted `control` file since I don't know how/when to use dpkg-gencontrol.

```
Package: my-package
Version: 1.0.0
Section: custom
Priority: optional
Architecture: arm64
Essential: no
Installed-Size: 28193
Maintainer: martin
Homepage: https://github.com/xxxx
Description: xxxx
Depends: net-tools, logrotate
```

The problem is the Installed-Size doesn't match and I get a warning like:

```
"W: Repository is broken: (my-package = 1.0.0)* has no Size information"
```

installing the package. I really want to be complient here, so any tips on how to incorporate dpkg-gencontrol or calc the size or get rid of that W message would be great appreciated.

Comment: If this only happens when reinstalling the same version of a previously installed package, it might be due to this known issue: https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/merge_requests/177